# Problem pausing the app while getting permission from user

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to get location data but first I have to get permission from the user. so i want to pause the app while the user grants or denies the permission

this is how I tried to do it:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME = 15000;
    private static final float LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE = 500;
    public static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public Boolean locationPermissionResults=null;

    double longitudeNetwork;
    double latitudeNetwork;
    TextView locationText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        locationText=findViewById(R.id.locationtext);

        //getting the permission if its not granted
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationText.setText("give permission1");
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        //resume if granted
        }
        else{
            locationManager();
        }




    }

    private final LocationListener mLocationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

            latitudeNetwork = location.getLatitude();
            longitudeNetwork = location.getLongitude();
            locationText.setText(Double.toString(longitudeNetwork) + "//" + Double.toString(latitudeNetwork));
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void locationManager(){
        LocationManager locationManagerNetwork = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManagerNetwork.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME,
                LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mLocationListenerNetwork);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        locationManager();

                    } else{
                        locationText.setText("give permission2");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have a problem with getting permission and handling the result. when the user denies the or grants the permission request the `locationText` shows `give permission1` which means the moved over the first `else` in `onCreate` method and also the `else` in `onRequestPermissionsResult`.
why is this happening?

NOTE: in `onRequestPermissionsResult` I'm only checking for one of the permissions asked in `onCreate` because if one of them is granted the other one is granted too. can this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pause an app.  Nor can you wait on the main thread.  You need to reorganize your Activity so you don't need to do that-  create an empty or waiting state that displays until that data is available.